# Bootstrap Table Width

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the table width, I want to auto adjust the width of the table header. How to do this?

How do I turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to auto adjust the width of the table cells to its content. In that case you need to set the width of the table to "auto".

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7r9svcu9/

```
<table style="width: auto;" class="table table-striped table-condensed">...</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

table-response may serve your requirement.

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 table { table-layout: fixed; }
 table th, table td { overflow: hidden; }
</style>

<table class="span12">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 30%">Col 1</th>
      <th style="width: 20%">Col 2</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">Col 3</th>
      <th style="width: 30%">Col 4</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">Col 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1</th>
      <td>Val 2</th>
      <td>Val 3</th>
      <td>Val 4</th>
      <td>Val 5</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For more Reference http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/

Comment: I suppose he doesn't want to set specific percentage widths. Also you mixed <td> tags with </th> tags. Also from the span12 tag I assume this is Bootstrap 2?!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 <table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

Comment: You set the width to 100% which is exactly not what he wanted. He wanted to auto adjust the width.